# add column to existing column in r

Tags: r

How do I convert 2 columns from a data.frame onto 2 different columns?
I.E:

```
Data
    A B C D
    1 3 5 7
    2 4 6 8
```

to

```
Data
    A B
    1 3
    2 4
    5 7
    6 8
```

Comment: you need to use `reshape` command to reshape from wide to long. Type `?reshape` in console.

Comment: As @user227710 suggested you could also use `reshape(Data, direction='long', varying=list(c(1,3), c(2,4)))[2:3]`

Comment: Or with `data.table` v >= 1.9.5 `melt(setDT(df), measure = list(c(1, 3), c(2, 4)), value.name = c("A", "B"))[, .(A, B)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rbind

```
rbind(df[,1:2], data.frame(A = df$C, B = df$D))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a fast version of `rbind`, `rbindlist` from data.table:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), 2), function(i) df[,i:(i+1)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution but it requires to change names of the columns.

```
names(dat) <- c("A", "B", "A", "B")
merge(dat[1:2], dat[3:4], all = T)
 A B
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 5 7
4 6 8
```

And here is another solution more easy.

```
dat[3:4, ] <- dat[ ,3:4]
dat <- dat[1:2]
dat
  A B
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 5 7
4 6 8
```

Answer (score 2):

For scalability, a solution that will halve any even size data frame and append the rows:

```
half <- function(df) {m <- as.matrix(df)
dim(m) <- c(nrow(df)*2,ncol(df)/2)
nd <- as.data.frame(m)
names(nd) <- names(df[(1:dim(nd)[2])]);nd}

half(Data)
  A B
1 1 5
2 2 6
3 3 7
4 4 8
```